# How to resize components when tab pane is resized with mouse drag

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have implemented very simple mouse drag of the tab pane located at the center. The mouse resize is very basic and it's not working very well but for now I can drag the border of the tabs and increase the size.

[image]

Now I have found a problem. When I resize the tabs located at the center the components located next of the center are not pushed back and shrieked automatically as the user might expect, they are placed behind the component that I resize. Can I somehow set all component to be pushed back when I extend the main component with mouse drag?

Comment: Have you used SplitPane to separate these components?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like others here, I'd recommend using the `SplitPane` class to handle the splitting of the screen for you.  Here's a sample (based on your screenshot) of the split panes.  If you dislike the display of the divider bar, you can modify the CSS to suit your needs.

[image: Screenshot of sample code]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXSplitTabs extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("SplitTabs");
        stage.setWidth(700);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        //Setup Center and Right
        TabPaneWrapper wrapper = new TabPaneWrapper(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, .9);
        TabPane centerPane = new TabPane();
        centerPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));

        TabPane rightPane = new TabPane();
        rightPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));
        SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(rightPane, false);
        wrapper.addNodes(centerPane, rightPane);

        //Add bottom
        TabPane bottomPane = new TabPane();
        bottomPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));
        TabPaneWrapper wrapperBottom = new TabPaneWrapper(Orientation.VERTICAL, .7);
        wrapperBottom.addNodes(wrapper.getNode(), bottomPane);

        //Add left
        TabPane leftPane = new TabPane();
        leftPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));
        TabPaneWrapper wrapperleft = new TabPaneWrapper(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, .1);
        wrapperleft.addNodes(leftPane, wrapperBottom.getNode());

        Scene myScene = new Scene(wrapperleft.getNode());
        stage.setScene(myScene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public Tab generateTab(String name){
        Tab result = new Tab(name);
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane();
        TextArea text = new TextArea();
        content.setCenter(text);
        result.setContent(content);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FXSplitTabs.launch(args);
    }

    public static class TabPaneWrapper{
        SplitPane split;

        public TabPaneWrapper(Orientation o, double splitLocation){
            split = new SplitPane();

            //Change the CSS (uncomment if using an external css)
            //split.getStylesheets().add("test.css");

            split.setOrientation(o);
            split.setDividerPosition(0, splitLocation);
        }

        public void addNodes(final Node node1, final Node node2){
            //Add to the split pane
            split.getItems().addAll(node1, node2);
        }

        public Parent getNode(){
            return split;
        }
    }

}
```

And if you wanted to use the CSS to change how the dividers look, uncomment the CSS line of code above, create a file `test.css` in the base package, and insert css specifications (here's an example that turns the dividers transparent):

```
.split-pane-divider {
   -fx-border-color: transparent;
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Your example is very good and easy for implement. But there is one more question which I would like to ask. If I want to switch the places between two tab panes how I can do it? In this example I can only implement basic resize.

Comment: I assume you mean taking all the tabs from the "Right" side and switching them to the "Left" side?  You'd have to keep track of your `SplitPane`s and `add`/`remove` nodes appropriately from them.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea but one by one. Can you give me some hits how this cam be implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're having problems with.  Do you have a question open with it?  You'd use the `onMouseDragged` listener (use the setter) and call `startFullDrag()` in it.  Then you'd listen using `setOnMouseDragReleased` to see where it's going.

Comment: Is there any example where I can see how I can implement it?

Comment: Doing a quick search, I didn't find much.  It's mostly basic event handling: http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/01/mouseevents-in-javafx/ combined with the call to `startFullDrag()`: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2355499  I'd recommend opening up your own question as this is off topic from the original question.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution:

I've released a first Early Access version of [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DromblerFX), a new Rich Client Platform for JavaFX based on OSGi and Maven.

It also comes with an initial version of a [Docking Framework](http://wiki.drombler.org/DockingFramework), which seems something you are looking for.

You can read more about Drombler FX here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/12/drombler-fx-building-modular-javafx.html

Comment: I suppose that you're experienced JavaFX developer. Can you propose some native solution?

Comment: Well, I used nested SplitPanes to solve this problem (as @Shreyas Dave already suggested).

Comment: Is there any native solution?

Comment: What do you mean with "native" in the context of JavaFX?

Comment: Maybe to use setOnDragDetected implementation which adds component resize behavior.