# How to switch TabPanes places with mouse drag

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to extend this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393691/how-to-resize-components-when-tab-pane-is-resized-with-mouse-drag) of TabPanes implementation.

I'm interested is it somehow possible to drag TabPanes with the mouse in order to change the position of the TabPane with mouse drag. Basic explanation how this can be implemented will highly appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXSplitTabs extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("SplitTabs");
        stage.setWidth(700);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        //Setup Center and Right
        TabPaneWrapper wrapper = new TabPaneWrapper(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, .9);
        TabPane centerPane = new TabPane();
        centerPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));

        TabPane rightPane = new TabPane();
        rightPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));
        SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(rightPane, false);
        wrapper.addNodes(centerPane, rightPane);

        //Add bottom
        TabPane bottomPane = new TabPane();
        bottomPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));
        TabPaneWrapper wrapperBottom = new TabPaneWrapper(Orientation.VERTICAL, .7);
        wrapperBottom.addNodes(wrapper.getNode(), bottomPane);

        //Add left
        TabPane leftPane = new TabPane();
        leftPane.getTabs().addAll(generateTab("Tab 1"),generateTab("Tab 2"), generateTab("Tab 3"), generateTab("Tab N"));
        TabPaneWrapper wrapperleft = new TabPaneWrapper(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, .1);
        wrapperleft.addNodes(leftPane, wrapperBottom.getNode());

        Scene myScene = new Scene(wrapperleft.getNode());
        stage.setScene(myScene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public Tab generateTab(String name){
        Tab result = new Tab(name);
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane();
        TextArea text = new TextArea();
        content.setCenter(text);
        result.setContent(content);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FXSplitTabs.launch(args);
    }

    public static class TabPaneWrapper{
        SplitPane split;

        public TabPaneWrapper(Orientation o, double splitLocation){
            split = new SplitPane();

            //Change the CSS (uncomment if using an external css)
            //split.getStylesheets().add("test.css");

            split.setOrientation(o);
            split.setDividerPosition(0, splitLocation);
        }

        public void addNodes(final Node node1, final Node node2){
            //Add to the split pane
            split.getItems().addAll(node1, node2);
        }

        public Parent getNode(){
            return split;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly read this, it might help you in your task: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2387524

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding an `onDragDetected` listener and a `onMouseDragReleased` listener to all your `TabPanes`.

```
    TabPaneDrag drag = new TabPaneDrag();
    ...
    centerPane.setOnDragDetected(drag);
    centerPane.setOnMouseDragReleased(drag);
    ...
    rightPane.setOnDragDetected(drag);
    rightPane.setOnMouseDragReleased(drag);
```

In your listener, you can keep track of what pane started the drag and which pane ended the drag (Then switch them if necessary).  Here's a quick example (mind you, there's some special cases and and kinks and such I didn't bother with - And `findWrapper()` is a method that returns the `TabPaneWrapper` containing the `TabPane`):

```
public class TabPaneDrag implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
    Node start;
    Node end;

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED)){
            start = (Node)arg0.getSource();
            start.startFullDrag(); //allows events to fire on nodes besides source
        } else if(arg0.getEventType().equals(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED)){
            end = (Node)arg0.getSource();
            if(end != start){
                ObservableList<Node> startWrapper = findWrapper(start).split.getItems();
                ObservableList<Node> endWrapper = findWrapper(end).split.getItems();
                int startIndex = startWrapper.indexOf(start);
                int endIndex = endWrapper.indexOf(end);

                // Remove/Add  the TabbedPanes to the new order
                endWrapper.remove(endIndex);
                startWrapper.remove(startIndex);

                startWrapper.add(startIndex, end);
                endWrapper.add(endIndex, start);

            }
            start = null;
            end = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One additional question - where I can find advanced guides about JavaFX for topics like this? Every tutorial that I find is for very basic example?

Comment: The drag stuff:  I haven't found a very good resource for.  And I haven't found many definitive resources in general (sorry!).  So far Oracle really is taking the lead - I've seen some great videos from the Java One conference which really helped.  Mostly I use: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html  and the JavaDocs in frame mode: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?overview-summary.html

Comment: I tried to implement this but I don't know how to implement the Java method `findWrapper()`. What is the content of this method?

Comment: Hint: `if(wrapper.split.getItems().contains(toFind))`  where `toFind` is the node passed into the function and `wrapper` is an instance of `TaskPaneWrapper`